# Jquery vertical img rotator issues

Tags: jquery

I have a simple jquery rotator that is kinda buggy. I'm wondering what changes can make it go less jumpy and not stop on mouse over? thanks

[Link to jsfiddle rotator](http://jsfiddle.net/ca7Ef/76/)

```
#ticker {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 330px;
    width: 130px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #000;
    border-top: 5px #999;
    border-bottom: 5px #999;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem jumpy to me, what browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

remove this code ,to keep it working on mouse hover

```
ticker.mouseenter(function () {
    container.stop();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this code:

```
ticker.mouseenter(function () {
    container.stop();
});
```

and set another value for division:

```
var duration = (distance + currentTop) / 0.025;
```